# Using $_GET for a value assigned to separate anchor link

Tags: php, html, mysql, get

I have the following two anchor links:

```
<a href='/inc/delete_user_and_remove_flagged.php?user_id=$u_id'> Remove User </a>
<a href="/inc/remove_flagged.php?id=$thought_id">Remove post flagged</a>
```

I am currently working in `delete_user_and_remove_flagged.php`. The idea is that by using `$_GET` I can get `user_id` (from the first `<a>`), and `delete` the account `where id='$user_id'`.

But I also want to remove all the posts of the user whose account is being delete from the `flagged_posts` table. My `flagged_posts` table has the following structure:

```
id
thought_id
flagged_by_id
```

So the only way I can delete the users posts is by `thought_id`, which I am trying to `$_GET` from the second `<a>` link.

Here is my current approach:

```
// 1. Close users account.
// 2. Delete all flagged posts relating to deleted user.

// 1.
$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
$delete_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "UPDATE users SET closed = 'no' WHERE id = '$user_id' ");

// 2.
$post_id = $_GET['id'];
$del_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "DELETE FROM flagged_posts WHERE thought_id = '$post_id'");

//header ("Location: /admin_flagged.php");
echo $user_id. "" . $post_id;
```

As you can see, I am echoing the vars to see if it is obtaining the correct values. `$user_id` echo's the value of `9` which is correct, it is the `id` of the user logged in. But nothing is being echoed for `$post_id` which is making me think that I cannot use `$_GET` for a value assigned to another anchor link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put more than on parameter on one anchor tag so you could do

```
<a href='/inc/delete_user_and_remove_flagged.php?user_id=$u_id&thought_id=$thought_id'> Remove User </a>
<a href="/inc/remove_flagged.php?id=$thought_id">Remove post flagged</a>
```

And pass both id's on the same `Remove User` click

This would generate a `$_GET['user_id']` and a `$_GET['thought_id']` from the same single click

Comment: My thinking was way to complex, forgot about such an approach! Thank you, works perfectly :)

Comment: My always my pleasure to help a gentlemen